# Connect Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge on Mac OS to debug in Android Studio

Tags: android, macos

I've made all the steps to become a developer on the cellphone, and also enabled what is necessary.

I also have already used this samsung galaxy to debug on another computer, and worked just fine.

However my Mac (10.7 El Capitan) does not even recognize my cellphone when I plug on the USB.

So, I've looked for in a lot of sites to install the necessary drivers for the usb port. However, all of them recommend to install SmartSwitch or Kies3, which I've also downloaded.

But, both need the cellphone connected on the computer to install all the drivers I need. But, I can't even make my Mac recognize my samsung S6 edge.

Does anyone had also the same problem? What should I do to make this work? Debugging using the emulator does not solve my problem! I need to debug on the real device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not to use the fast charge cord for this purpose. Buy another android cord to debug